# PHP timeout while moving files with rename

Tags: php, apache, filesystems

While moving thousands of files using

```
foreach ($list_of_files as $file) {
    rename($file, 'another_folder/' . $file);
}
```

can PHP timeout in the middle of `rename()` causing one single file to be moved only partially?

Comment: few options: increase the time limit, use the server(os) functions,  run in background. your choose will depend on factors i know nothing of ;-)

Comment: A rename is an atomic syscall … It's uninterruptible. Either it's renamed or it isn't. There's nothing like partially renamed. [Well, in case of power failure  such things are always possible…]

Comment: Not only power failure, mabye just a pre-alpha of the filesystem that plays mumbo jumbo disco dance with data on disk for the fun. If you can't break it, it wasn't for real.

Comment: Please define *"partially moved"* - Can you elaborate why you mean by these tow words in your question?

Comment: @hakre The case when for example only a half of a file will be copied or maybe an empty file created with no data copied.

Comment: the move operation does not copy a file nor data. please relate to your system handbook what a move operation actually is and what happens when you do it for the filesystem you're using. which operating sstem are you using? which filesystem is the file placed on you move? and why do you tag the question with "apache"?